# React - Redux dispatch an action based on UI state

Tags: javascript, web, redux, react-redux, reducers

In my React component reducer state I have a selectedTabIndex property, specifying what tab is currently active in my UI.

```
const deviceRankReducer = (state = {
    selectedIndex:1
},action) ={
   //...
}
```

In my Redux action I want to make an AJAX call based on the selected tab index.

```
class MyActions extends ReduxActionsBase {
     sendRequest(){
          if(state.selectedIndex === 0){
             //make call to resource A
          }else{
             //make call to resource B
          }
     }
}
```

What is the best practice of sharing the information with the ReduxActionsBase without making an anti-pattern decision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk). `redux-thunk` allows you to dispatch conditional and async actions and you will have access to Redux state inside your action creator. Action creator in your case would be something like this

```
function makeRequest() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { selectedIndex } = getState();

    if(state.selectedIndex === 0){
      //make call to resource A
    }else{
      //make call to resource B
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can this be done without adding a 3rd party lib? I'm working within a given environment

Comment: `redux-thunk` is very, very often used in redux apps and it's hard to create redux apps without it or without something similar but if you can't install any 3rd party lib you'd have to write your own Redux `middleware`: http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html

Comment: redux-thunk is only about 12 lines long.  If you can't add it as an NPM dependency, it's trivial to copy-paste it into your application.